# Toast с Делением на ноль

Tags: java, android, деление

Как в Java проверить деление на ноль? Пишу небольшой калькулятор и нужно вывести Toast об ошибке ,что нельзя делить число num1 на ноль. 
Что-то я не соображаю как это реализовать.

Comment: ЧТо значит проверить деление? На ноль делить нельзя. Поэтому если делитель = 0, то на 0 делить нельзя

Comment: Зачем вы полезли к сообщениям и в частности к toast? Если вы затрудняетесь проверить делитель на равенство с нулем? Вам бы сначала прокачать логику, а потом курить простейшие алгоритмы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оберните свой код в `try-catch` и ловите `java.lang.ArithmeticException` — тогда при подобной ошибке вылетит исключение, а вы в свою очередь покажете Toast с ошибкой.

Но лучше проверять все действия, прежде чем их выполнять, ибо проверка вводимых данных — основа основ.

Answer (score -1):

```
private void calculate(double x, double y){
  if (x != 0 || y != 0) {
    //calc here
  } else {
    //make toast here
  }
}
```

Пойдет такой вариант?

Comment: А почему делимое не может быть нулем?

Comment: Если что делимое может быть нулем.

Comment: Я всего лишь показал пример как сделать проверку, под себя поправить кажется труда не составит. Это менее ресурсо-затратно, чем кидать исключения на таких операциях.